# Could a component be instantiated with an arbitrary type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given this code, why do I get the following error?

What I'm trying to say is, here is a Component, and its props (...otherProps). When I give you that component and its props, render them together.

This feels like an anti-pattern, but I would love to know what the correct way to resolve this with Typescript is. Many thanks to anyone who can help.

**Edit**
You might be wondering why I don't just render the component. This is for my academic understanding of Typescript, not an actual use case. I don't understand why, if I'm specifying the prop types and saying that the component takes those props, I can't simply render the component.

```js
function Comp<C>({
  Component,
  ...otherProps
}: {
  Component: ComponentType<C>
} & C) {
  return <Component {...otherProps} />
}
```

> Type 'Omit<{ Component: ComponentType; } & C, "Component">' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & C & { children?: ReactNode;
> }'.   Type 'Omit<{ Component: ComponentType; } & C, "Component">'
> is not assignable to type 'C'.
> 'C' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Omit<{ Component: ComponentType; } & C,
> "Component">'.